# How to use selenium to click on date symbol and enter dates?

Tags: python, selenium

I have to scrape data from a website. I have to click on each date from june 2019 to july 2019 and download data from that resulting page. Right now, I am unable to click on the calender icon and enter dates which is stopping me to go further. Is there a way to do this?

```py
import bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

link = "http://apsdps.ap.gov.in/pages/reports_web/reports_daily_mandalwise.html"

webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(link)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='Zebra_DatePicker_Icon_Wrapper']").click
```

Comment: Do you have any error??

Comment: last line: it should be .click()

Comment: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='Zebra_DatePicker_Icon_Wrapper']"}

Comment: I tried with .click(). The above error pops up.

Comment: TRY: 
***WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='Zebra_DatePicker_Icon_Wrapper']")))*** before clicking on element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is within iframe. you have to switch to the iframe and try click on the element.

```
    driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_name("date1").click()
```

Comment: It worked! Can you please tell me how to enter the date from there?

Answer (score 0):

This is How I did in my project.
Use send_keys to enter the date.

```
# //*[@id="txtDateFrom"]
datefield = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtDateFrom"]')
datefield.click()
datefield.clear()

datefield.send_keys("01/01/2018")

time.sleep(4)

datefield = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtDateTo"]')
datefield.click()
datefield.clear()
datefield.send_keys("3/02/2018")
```